# Can Python be run from within the vim editor?

Tags: python, vim

Is it possible to run Python code from within the vim editor?

What is necessary to install the support along with Python syntax highlighting?

How would I install "python.vim : Enhanced version of the python syntax highlighting script" ?

I did not automatically create ~/.vim/syntax and I'm using a Mac, all I downloaded was the .app file, an executable that I don't know of its purpose and a readme file.

I've tried also creating a folder for the python.vim file, but that didn't work out either.

Comment: You don't have to manually "compile" Python. The interpreter does that for you, potentially making a `.pyc` file. Anyway; what is it that you actually want to do?

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to both python and vim. I just wanted to find a good ide and run a test python script. I meant to say run, not compile.

Comment: If you are looking for an IDE your are looking in the wrong direction: Vim is text editor.

Comment: When you installed vim, I believe a ~/.vim should have been installed too. Vim is a lighter weight IDE than say Eclipse, but it and Emacs are used extensively with Clojure, but I am not sure about Python.

Answer (score 19):

Personally:

1. When inside Vim editing my Python scripts, I simply hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> so as to return in console mode.
2. Run my script with command `$ python my_script.py`.
3. When done, I enter `$ fg` in the command line and that gets me back inside Vim, in the state I was before hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>. *(fg as in foreground)*

---

**Edit**

Recently I have started using the `:terminal` mode of vim much more frequently.
I tend to prefer it to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>Z because it may happen that I forget that I used Ctrl-z and open an additional vim session: it may become messy. Also, having a terminal pane is easier for dealing with line number in errors message, since the two views are available at the same time.

So the workflow I'm using nowadays has become:

1. `:terminal`  (in my case I have a vim mapping with leader key) `<leader>tm :terminal<cr>` so that I don't even type `:terminal` manually)
2. Run my script with command `$ python my_script.py`.
3. `$ exit` in the bash command line if I want to close the terminal pane

Answer (score 9):

You don't have to install any plugins to get syntax highlighting for any version of Python in Vim. The *python-syntax* plugin might have more features, but it's absolutely not needed and not important if you're new to Vim and Python. To enable syntax highlighting add this to your `~/.vimrc`:

```
filetype plugin on
syntax on
```

Adding to Kent's answer you can also send arguments to the script you're running if you want to.
`[args]` is something you'd normally add after `python script.py`.

```
:w !python - [args]
```

Personally I prefer to have a seperate shell open in [Tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/) for running my scripts, and possibly play around with [bpython](http://www.bpython-interpreter.org/about/). If I'm not using a Tmux session `:sh` works fine too, giving you a normal shell. You can get back to vim by doing `exit` or <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>d</kbd>.

As for using Python with vim autocomplete is a big part of it, and I can recommend [jedi-vim](https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi-vim) for this. If you want error checking/magic [Syntastic](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic) is the tool for the job.

---

This might be a little overwhelming if you're new to both Vim and Python, but I suggest you take it as it comes, step by step. The first step for learning Vim is to do the Vimtutor. Run it by entering `vimtutor` in a shell.

Comment: Would there be any way to make :w !python - [args] a shortcut and also pass in arguments?

Comment: Alright I'll try out vimtutor

Comment: @Anonymous I'll update my answer with a remapping (keybind) for `:w !python - [args]` in a couple of minutes or so. As for vimtutor I have to ask; do you use *nix, for example Linux or OS X? If you're using Windows you'd have to run the Vimtutor from `C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim73\vimtutor.bat` or similar.

Comment: @Anonymous Good thing. Then it should be installed and runnable from a shell (terminal) without a problem if I'm correct.

Comment: @Anonymous I'm sorry, my vimscript-fu is lacking and I couldn't make an elegant function that takes optional argument(s) for such a command AND make it available as a keybind (it'd have to ask for any arguments aswell). When you know vim `:w !python - [args]` isn't hard to remember, and as such I haven't even thought about making it easier. There might be someone else that has a better solution for it, but I personally prefer to use another shell using Tmux or `:sh` as mentioned.

Comment: just fyi: `:h input()` to get user input. better use it between inputsave and inputrestore.

Comment: @Kent Aye, it'd have to be something like that but I can't really say I see the point. There's little gain for a lot of pain, it's not hard to just write the command. If the code is normally run without any code this would be sufficient though: `nnoremap <F9> :w !python<CR>`

Comment: I prefer tmux too (or ctrl-z/fg) because in most case, we edit bar.py, but the application should be started from foo.py. I commented it because OP asked.

Comment: @Kent That, and I'd usually have to have another window for bpython anyway :-)

Answer (score 4):

If you are asking how to run Python code through vim, try this:

**EDIT**

thank **@Zyx** for pointing out the problems in my original line, I leave this line here, in order to let reader know where are the problems.

```
nmap <F9> :!python %<cr>
```

you could create this au (I saved has("autocmd") part...) in your vimrc:

```
autocmd FileType python nnoremap <buffer> <F9> :exec '!python' shellescape(@%, 1)<cr>
```

put this in your .vimrc, then after you editing your .py file, press `<f9>` vim will try to compile and execute it (via external python interpreter).

how to install that plugin:

https://github.com/hdima/python-syntax#how-to-install

Comment: I found a .vminfo file that begins like this: "# This viminfo file was generated by Vim 7.3. # You may edit it if you're careful!" Is this the same as .vimrc?

Comment: @Anonymous No, the `.vimrc` file is called... `.vimrc` :-)

Comment: @Anonymous the vimrc is the initializing file when vim is loaded.  It setups preferences and imports plugins either by using pathogen autoload or something else.  You can also specify indentation, paren matching, etc

Comment: @Anonymous from your comment, I feel you are still a bit far away from enjoying coding python in vim. I suggest you "stealing" some .vimrc file first, and take a look those common options.  .vimrc should be in your `$HOME/.vimrc`, if you don't have the file, create one.

Comment: I don't know why this was marked down, but it's a decent answer IMHO.

Comment: Such simple command and two errors here. First, [don’t use `nmap`](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/05.html). Second, don’t use `%`: it is not going to work with arbitrary filename (namely the one containing special characters such as space) there is `:execute "!python" shellescape(@%, 1)` for this job.

Comment: @octopusgrabbus Because there are two serious mistakes which are fine in case you are using temporary mapping for one vim session only and should not ever be there once written anywhere else.

Comment: @ZyX ok, I accept the downvote. I didn't think too much when I wrote that line, just wanted to make it short.

Comment: Well, if you clean up the problem, perhaps you'll get un-downvoted.

Comment: @octopusgrabbus I updated the answer. pointed out my mistakes and also wrote a new line, hope it is ok this time.